# Having trouble implementing a color form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been following a react tutorial on LinkedIn and I got to the part where you implement a customhook. From the screen there were no errors however when I submit the form the color code is listed as "undefined"

[image: 1]

Here is the code in react

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
function useInput(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  return [
    {
      value, 
      onChange: (e) => setValue(e.target.value)
    },
    () => setValue(initialValue)
  ]

}

function App() {
  const [titleProps, resetTitle] = useInput("");
  const [colorProps, resetColor] = useState("#000000");
  const submit = (e) => {//functionm which handles submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(`${titleProps.value}, ${colorProps.value}`);
    resetTitle();//resets name
    resetColor("#000000");//resets color
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <input
        {...titleProps}
        type="text"
        placeholder="color title..."
      />
      <input
        {...colorProps}
        type="color"
      />
      <button>ADD</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I open the console I received the following errors

```
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `0`
input
form
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44:44 react-dom.development.js:67
    React 19
    js index.js:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
```

When inspecting the error I found out it had something to do with this react-dom.development.js file particularly this line

```
Function.prototype.apply.call(console[level], console, argsWithFormat);
```

I am not sure how to resolve this so I am coming to the community to aid me in resolving this error

I tried to implement a custom hook but have met errors along the way. How would I fix this?

Comment: `colorProps` is a string, there is no `.value` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, except you used `useState` instead of `useInput` on line

```
const [colorProps, resetColor] = useState("#000000");
```

You can check out my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-resonance-re291w?file=/src/App.js)